# Wrong description for abstract badge tag

Tags: bug, localization, tag-badges, internationalization

The hint on badges page has "Bronze/Silver/Gold Badge" instead of some particular badge's name.

> bronze badge: Earn at least 100 total score for at least 20 non-community wiki answers **in the Bronze Badge tag**.

> [image]

In Transifex the strings for descriptions of particular tags are numbers 6653-6655 (they differ only in number: one/few/many):

> Earn at least $score$ total score for at least $answerScoreStr$ non-community wiki answers in the $tagLink$ tag

I doubt there is a [bronze-badge](/questions/tagged/bronze-badge) tag. Thus, a different string should be used here, something like this:

> Earn at least $score$ total score for at least $answerScoreStr$ non-community wiki answers in a particular tag

At least it should have `$score$` and `$answerScoreStr$`, but not `$tagLink$`. This should be enough to localize it the right way.

Comment: This issue still exists: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQ127.png